# Unable to upload iOS IPA to Apple

Tags: ios, javafx, javafxports

The generated IPA runs fine and installs on the device. However, the Gradle build script produces a faulty IPA, apparently, unsuitable for upload to Apple.

Here's one of them:

ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. **This app was built with an unknown SDK**. All new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS '11.0' SDK or later, included in Xcode [9.0] or later. Please update Xcode and rebuild your app."

So in this case, how would I go about specifying the correct SDK? I am using the latest (9.4) Xcode Version 9.4.1 (9F2000), macOS HighSierra 10.13.5

I could not find a property in the Gradle build settings to advise the build script of this version.

------- UPDATE 6/23/18 ---------

I updated my pList file to match yours and now I get only the following error:

ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle [Payload/app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."

Here is my pList (I'll follow up with build.gradle next):

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>

    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.my.App</string>

    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>       

    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>

    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>my-App</string>        

    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>Icon-60</string>
        <string>Icon-76</string>
        <string>Icon-Small-50</string>    
        <string>Icon-Small</string>
    </array>

    <key>CFBundleIconFiles~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>Icon-76</string>
        <string>Icon-Small-50</string>
        <string>Icon-Small</string>
    </array>    

    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>my-App</string>

    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>

    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>    

    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>    

    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>

    <!-- Turns off iPad Multitasking -->
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <string>YES</string> 

    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>

    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>

    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <integer>2</integer>
    </array>

    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>        

    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>9.0</string>    

    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <string>YES</string>

    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key> 
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string> 

    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key> 
    <false/>

    <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
    <false/>

    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
    <dict>  
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>  
        <dict>  
            <key>gluonhq.com</key>  
            <dict>  
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>  
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>  
            </dict>
            <key>www.oracle.com</key>  
            <dict>  
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>  
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>  
            </dict>  
        </dict>  
    </dict>  

    <key>UILaunchImages</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-375w-667h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{375, 667}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-414w-736h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{414, 736}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{768, 1024}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-ipad105</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{834, 1112}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-ipad129</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{1024, 1366}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>7.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-568h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 568}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>6.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 480}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict> 
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key> 
            <string>11.0</string> 
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-812h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key> 
            <string>{375, 812}</string> 
        </dict>
    </array>

</dict>
```

--------------------- build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.10'
    }
}

// ******************** Java Plugin

apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    ...
}

// ******************** Java FX Ports Mobile Plugin

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.my.App'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:glisten-afterburner:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.gluonhq:connect:1.4.3'
}

jfxmobile {

    javafxportsVersion = '8.60.9'

    downConfig {
        version = '3.6.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }

    ios {

        assetsDirectory = 'src/ios/resources/assets/'

        infoPList = file('src/ios/resources/Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [             
            'com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.ios.IOSLogService',
            'com.gluonhq.**.*',

            ...
        ]   
    }
}

// ******************** Java Gluon Plugin

apply from: 'ios-build.gradle'

task xcodebuild {
    doLast {
        xcodebuildIOS("$project.buildDir","$project.projectDir", "Log")
    }
}

task installNativeLib (type: Copy, dependsOn: xcodebuild) {
    from( "$project.buildDir/native" )
    into( "src/ios/jniLibs" )
    include( "*.a" )
}

======== ios-build.gradle

if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase().contains("mac")) {
    new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
        exec {
            args '-version', '-sdk', 'iphoneos', 'SDKVersion'
            executable 'xcodebuild'
            standardOutput = os
        }
        ext.IOS_VERSION = os.toString().trim()
    }
} else {
    ext.IOS_VERSION = ""
}
ext.IS_DEBUG_NATIVE = Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("IS_DEBUG_NATIVE", "false"))

def sdkPath(String platform) {

    return "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/${platform}.platform/Developer/SDKs/${platform}${IOS_VERSION}.sdk";
}

ext.xcodebuildIOS = {buildDir, projectDir, name ->

    if (!file(sdkPath('iPhoneOS')).exists()) {
        return
    }

    println "IOS_VERSION: " + ${IOS_VERSION}

    def buildSystems = ["iPhoneOS+arm64",
                        "iPhoneOS+armv7",
                        "iPhoneSimulator+i386",
                        "iPhoneSimulator+x86_64"]
    def linkerOutputs = []
    def lipoOutput = "$buildDir/native/lib${name}.a"
    def nativeSources = ["$projectDir/src/ios/native/${name}.m"]

    buildSystems.each { buildSystem ->

        def (platform, arch) = buildSystem.tokenize("+");
        def compileOutput = "$buildDir/native/$arch"
        def compileOutputs = ["$buildDir/native/$arch/${name}.o"]
        def linkerOutput = "$buildDir/native/$arch/lib${name}.a"
        new File(compileOutput).mkdirs();

        def clangArgs = [
                "-x", "objective-c",
                "-miphoneos-version-min=6.0",
                "-fmessage-length=0",
                "-std=c99",
                "-fno-common",
                "-Wall",
                "-fno-strict-aliasing",
                "-fwrapv",
                "-fpascal-strings",
                "-fobjc-abi-version=2",
                "-fobjc-legacy-dispatch",
                "-I" + System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") + "/include",
                "-I" + System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") + "/include/darwin",
                "-c",
            IS_DEBUG_NATIVE ? ["-O0", "-DDEBUG", "-g"] : ["-O3", "-DNDEBUG"],
                "-arch", arch,
                "-isysroot",
            sdkPath(platform),
            nativeSources].flatten()

        def linkerArgs = [
                "-static",
                "-framework", "Foundation",
                "-framework", "CoreGraphics",
                "-framework", "CoreBluetooth",
                "-framework", "CoreLocation",
                "-framework", "CoreMotion",
                "-framework", "CoreText",
                "-framework", "UIKit",
                "-framework", "QuartzCore",
                "-framework", "OpenGLES",
                "-framework", "UserNotifications",
                "-arch_only", arch,
                "-syslibroot", sdkPath(platform),
                "-L${sdkPath(platform)}/usr/lib",
                "-o", linkerOutput,
            compileOutputs
        ].flatten()

        exec {
            executable "clang"
            args clangArgs
            workingDir compileOutput
        }

        exec {
            executable "libtool"
            args linkerArgs
            workingDir compileOutput
        }

        linkerOutputs.add(linkerOutput)
    }

    def lipoArgs = [
            "-create",
        linkerOutputs,
            "-o",
        lipoOutput
    ].flatten();

    exec {
        executable "lipo"
        args lipoArgs
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages from iTunesConnect when you submit the app? Have you tried to fix them? If that didn't work, post them here. Otherwise it will be impossible to help you.

Comment: thanks for replying - yes, I tried to fix all errors. In most cases, they make no sense. I edited the post to add the most perplexing error

Comment: See this [Default-info.plist](https://github.com/devoxx/MyDevoxxGluon/blob/master/DevoxxClientMobile/src/ios/Default-Info.plist) in case you are missing some key. In case it doesn't solve the issue, post your build.gradle and plist files (at least the relevant information)

Comment: ok, JoséPereda It's all up there. Thanks so much for looking at this

Comment: The error `Invalid Provisioning Profile`, is quite clear. You need a valid Distribution Provisioning profile from the Apple Developer portal, and then you need to use it to sign the app.You can use `iosProvisioningProfile` and `iosSignIdentity` (see [docs](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/5.0.0/#_ios_2)) inside your build-> jfxmobile->iOS block.

Comment: I've tried that - doesn't work. I have valid profiles, have submitted native apps to the app store for years successfully. When I set the iosProvisioningProfile and iosSignIdentity I get completely different results, also errors. Perhaps the profiles have become corrupted, not sure. Guess I'll go with the last resort and start all over with new profiles and see what happens.

Comment: If you run `./gradlew —info createIPA` on a terminal you can track which provisioning profile and signing identify are used. Then you can check if those are the correct ones. If that’s not the case, you have to set the right ones as I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. But it points me now back to square 1.
Error Messages:
ERROR ITMS-90035: "Invalid Signature. A sealed resource is missing or invalid. The file at path [] is not properly signed. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate.
ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with an unknown SDK. All new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS '11.0' SDK or later, included in Xcode [9.0] or later. Please update Xcode and rebuild your app."

Comment: I only have 2 certificates and 2 provisioning profiles. Both of them are signed and built correctly according to the Apple developer portal. I am building with the latest Xcode and the “createIPA” portion of the Gradle build script is pulling the correct signing identity and provisioning profile. So, both of these error messages are completely erroneous - something else is blowing up the acceptance script at Apple.

Comment: That only leaves two possibilities. One, there’s something askew with my Xcode project, which I have started over with and rebuilt multiple times, making sure that the IPA is signed properly and built in release mode. Or two, there is something wrong with the Gradle script that prepares the IPA file for submission to the App Store.

There’s only six gazillion options in an Xcode build project. Would it be possible to get a copy of an Xcode project used to successfully submit?

Comment: Do you have push notifications enabled? If so, the provisioning profile should include this extra feature (same goes for in-app purchases and others) and you need to specify `apsEnvironment="production"` in the build file. Also, you may need to set the arch to `arch = 'arm64'`. The Devoxx app linked above is regularly deployed to the Apple store. As for Xcode, maybe you can try to create an empty project, with the same bundle id, and check that can be signed with your provisioning profile.

Comment: Thanks, tried all of that. I contacted Gluon support, but there seems to be nobody home there ...

Comment: Note that Gluon's basic support is also offered directly through StackOverflow, as this is open and could benefit other users that might face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number as the first in your bundle id, it is not currently supported by apple!

Comment: Thanks for replying, but that's not my case - my bundle ID starts with the canonical com.xxxx